# Thunderbird Default Language Fail: Canadian English for California, Configuration Rejection, and No Alternatives

Tags: thunderbird, language

Thunderbird persistently offers only Canadian English as the default language option - I'm in California so God knows why.

Worse, it disregards having previously been configured for American English.

Even worse, notwithstanding having downloaded and installed every available American English language add-in, Thunderbird offers none of them as an option.

Google offers no insights.  Any thoughts about how to bring the app to heel would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed any add-ons? At worst, save your user profile, uninstall Thunderbird, reinstall and return your profile.

Comment: See the OP: "Even worse, notwithstanding having downloaded and installed every available American English language add-in, Thunderbird offers none of them as an option."

Comment: Reinstall, and check if the problem still exists before returning your profile. If the problem exists only with your profile, use another one.

Comment: @harrymc, thanks.  What you're saying is that this is a case of configuration resistance, if overhauling the installation or profile is the only available fix.  How humiliating for the developers.

Answer (score 0):

If https://thunderbird.net/ is offering you Canadian English, I would expect that to be caused by your browser environment.

You can pick the language directly in https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/all/

Comment: My browser settings are set to U.S. English, actually.